# Selenium C# Extent report is not generating HTML file in the specified folder

Tags: selenium, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am trying to generate a report in HTML using Extent report (version="3.1.3") for Selenium Webdriver C#, but in the specified folder i am not able to see the HTML file after successful execution of test script.

It would be great if you could help me in identifying what is wrong and provide a solution for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Please find below for the code snippet.

```
namespace Selenium_Demo_01
 {
[TestFixture]
public class Demo01
{
    IWebDriver driver;
    Program dataDriven = new Program();

    public ExtentReports extent;
    public ExtentTest test;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void ClassSetup()
    {
        var reportPath = new ExtentHtmlReporter(@"I:\Selenium\VS Project 
                                            files\Selenium_Demo_01\
                                                       Selenium_Demo_01\Reports\Demo_Report_01.html");

        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.AttachReporter(reportPath);
    }

    [Test]
    public void test_D365Login()
    {
        test = extent.CreateTest("test_D365Login");

        string webTitle, webTitle1;

        //Get web page Title
        driver.Url = appURL;
        webTitle = driver.Title;
        System.Console.WriteLine(webTitle);

        Assert.AreEqual(title1, webTitle);
        test.Pass("Assertion passed");

        //Get web page Title
        webTitle1 = driver.Title;
        System.Console.WriteLine(webTitle1);

        Assert.AreEqual(title2, webTitle1);
        test.Pass("Assertion passed");
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void closeBrowser()
    {
        var status = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status;
        var stacktrace = string.IsNullOrEmpty(TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.StackTrace)
                ? ""
                : string.Format("{0}", 
                       TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.StackTrace);
        Status logstatus;

        switch (status)
        {
            case TestStatus.Failed:
                logstatus = Status.Fail;
                break;
            case TestStatus.Inconclusive:
                logstatus = Status.Warning;
                break;
            case TestStatus.Skipped:
                logstatus = Status.Skip;
                break;
            default:
                logstatus = Status.Pass;
                break;
        }

        test.Log(logstatus, "Test ended with " + logstatus + stacktrace);
        extent.RemoveTest(test);
        extent.Flush();
        driver.Close();
    }
```

}

Extent-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extentreports>
<configuration>
    <!-- report theme -->
    <!-- standard, dark -->
    <theme>standard</theme>

    <!-- document encoding -->
    <!-- defaults to UTF-8 -->
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>

    <!-- protocol for script and stylesheets -->
    <!-- defaults to https -->
    <protocol>https</protocol>

    <!-- title of the document -->
    <documentTitle>Automation testing</documentTitle>

    <chartVisibilityOnOpen>true</chartVisibilityOnOpen>

    <!-- report name - displayed at top-nav -->
    <reportName>Automation Report - Shashank R</reportName>

    <!-- location of charts in the test view -->
    <!-- top, bottom -->
    <testViewChartLocation>bottom</testViewChartLocation>

    <!-- custom javascript -->
    <scripts>
        <![CDATA[
            $(document).ready(function() {

            });
        ]]>
    </scripts>

    <!-- custom styles -->
    <styles>
        <![CDATA[

        ]]>
    </styles>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You need to share where it is locating currently,

Comment: Hi Ishita, the report is not locating to any path currently. I mean, the report is not generated/created at all after execution.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the step and check whether Report is generating or not, 
Make sure your Test execution completed correctly, And extent.fluch() was call. Else, Extent Report can't generate.

1. Create Folder in your project Workspace named as "eReport"
2. Create variable name as reportLocation = "./eReport/" + "TestReport.html";
3. Pass reportLocation variable to ExtentHTMlReport method,

   var reportPath = new ExtentHtmlReporter(reportLocation);

And further you may check, it is generated or not.

You may try with Basic example from their official Doc, 
http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/net/#examples

Comment: Thank you Ishita, i had followed in the same way, but still i am not able to get the report.

Comment: Is there any exception you are getting? Please share more details,

Comment: Do not implement things directly in your project, First try with basic example without project dependency so you can have step ideas.

Comment: There are no exceptions i am facing, also i debugged the code and saw extent.Flush() being called. So, i am stuck here in identifying what is wrong.

Comment: Hi Ishita, i tried with another project (Different machine as well) which has basic example, even in this i was not able to generate report. Could you please help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below for the code snippet:

```
[TestFixture]
class Demo
{
    public ExtentReports extent;
    public ExtentTest test;

    [SetUp]
    public void TestSetup()
    {
        var reportPath = new ExtentHtmlReporter
            (@"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Selenium_D365\Selenium_D365\eReports\Demo_Report_01.html");
        //var reportLocation = "./Reports/" + "TestReport.html";
        //var reportPath = new ExtentHtmlReporter(reportLocation);
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.AttachReporter(reportPath);
    }

    [Test]
    public void test_D365Login()
    {
        test = extent.CreateTest("test_D365Login");

        Assert.IsTrue(true);
        test.Pass("Assertion passed");
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        var status = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status;
        var stacktrace = string.IsNullOrEmpty(TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.StackTrace);
        Status logstatus = Status.Pass;

        test.Log(logstatus, "Test ended with " + status + stacktrace);

        extent.RemoveTest(test);
        extent.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using @ on reportPath ? Please remove and check .

Comment: @ is a verbatim string to use the value within the string as is. Anyhow i had tried without that, but no luck.

Answer (score -1):

You have load the extent-config file location in HTML object.

```
reportPath.LoadConfig("Extent-config.xml")
```